# Facebook API -- embed a video in a wall post that also has another link

Tags: facebook, video, hyperlink, facebook-wall

I'm trying to make a wall post using the Facebook API that has a playable video thumbnail and a link field. (I am using the Facebook Python wrapper).

When you make a wall post using the API, you specify your extra content with an attachment field:

```
graph = GraphAPI(valid_access_token)
graph.put_wall_post(message="Hey Everyone", attachment={
  "name" : "My Cool Link",
  "description" : "It's very cool",
  "link" : "http://www.my_app_url.com"
 }
```

I want to add a playable video thumbnail to this.  One way to do it is to put the video url in the link field of the attachment:

```
graph.put_wall_post(message="Hey Everyone", attachment={
  "name" : "My Cool Video",
  "description" : "It's very cool",
  "link" : "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=some_yt_id"
 }
```

This renders a video thumbnail and is playable in Facebook, which is what I want, but it uses up the "link" field, so I can't use that field to link them to www.my_app_url.com.  I want to be able to do both.

**Anyone know how I can put a playable video thumbnail *and* a link to my app in a Facebook wall post through the Open Graph API?**

*Additional background info*:  There is a way to do this sort of thing with the a "picture" field in the attachment object -- this allows you to add a picture url which is separate from the main link of the attachment. The facebook docs *say* you can put video links in a field called "source" in the attachment, but when I tried it, the attachment didn't render the thumbnail, and it wouldn't play.

Comment: Where exactly does the docs say you can use source in the attachment?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/.

Comment: Although technically it just says that posts "have the following fields"... it does not say for sure that you can set them all by specifying them in the attachment.  So I may have misread it.

Comment: That's for reading the object, these are the fields you can create with http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting the link to my app in the message of the post, and using the 'link' field in the post attachment for the video.  Not what I was hoping for but I guess it does work.